# Iframe source with variable

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, encoding

I have a couple of questions:

1. Is `<iframe src="/index.php"></iframe>` the same as HTMLIFrameElement ?
2. Why

   ```
   <iframe src="data:text/html;base64,aHR0cDovL2V4YW1wbGUuY29t"
       height=1280 width=800></iframe>
   ```

   works fine, but

   ```
   a=document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
   b=document.createElement('iframe');
   b.src="data:text/html;base64,aHR0cDovL2V4YW1wbGUuY29t";
   a.appendChild(b);
   ```

   does not work? I mean in DOM HTMLIFrameElement src I could put function with encoded string. Is it possible to encode string only in src variable?

Comment: Just putting it here so everyone can see that the whole premise of your question is false. http://jsfiddle.net/JkJNH/2/ <-- they work exactly the same, and that code is pretty much directly copypasted from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Data URI scheme is for direct embedded data.

```
data:text/html;base64,aHR0cDovL2V4YW1wbGUuY29t
```

Means a html page with `"http://example.com"` as its sole content.

You probably want `"http://example.com"` as `src`

Comment: I need what it will work like this jsfiddle.net/maniator/JkJNH/1 but with  src="data:text/html;base64,aHR0cDovL2V4YW1wbGUuY29t";

Comment: @Adam Why? `data:` does not work like that, so you cannot do it. Read my answer.

Comment: But why it work for `<iframe src="data:text/html;base64,aHR0cDovL2V4YW1wbGUuY29t" height=1280 width=800></iframe>`???

Comment: @Adam ? that doesn't work like the jsfiddle you gave.. see http://jsfiddle.net/44xwN/

Comment: So there are no ways to encode URL or get URL in src from variable?

Comment: @Adam yes like this http://jsfiddle.net/JkJNH/3/ `atob` is Base64Decode function that only works in chrome or firefox, you must supply it manually if you need it to work in IE.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes
2. You need to append the iFrame to the document. [Like so](http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/JkJNH/) `document.body.appendChild(b)​`

Comment: i have do it "a.appendChild(b);" but stil do not work, only works whit clearly link "http://www.example.com" or link concatinated with + ""http://"+"www.example.com"

Comment: if i write src="http://example.com"; iframe redirect me to that page but if i write src="data:text/html;base64,aHR0cDovL2V4YW1wbGUuY29t"; just see text decoded by base64

Comment: But can you put in src="data:text/html;base64,aHR0cDovL2V4YW1wbGUuY29t"; and show how it is work for you please? I need what it will work like this http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/JkJNH/1/

Comment: @Neal this answer is useless, he was already appending it to body. `a === document.body` in his question :<

Comment: @Esailija how do you know this?

Answer (score 0):

To your point 2: your two methods give the same result.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ft9gh/

```
a=document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
b=document.createElement('iframe');
b.src="data:text/html;base64,aHR0cDovL2V4YW1wbGUuY29t";
a.appendChild(b); ​
```