# Is there a way to embed github code into an iframe?

Tags: iframe, github

The question may seem confusing so let me clarify.

Github lets you see the source code of a files in a repo. I want to include them in iframes but am unsure how and suspect someone has already done this before.

In my case I want to add https://github.com/ileathan/hubot-mubot/blob/master/src/mubot.coffee to an iframe so that from my website people can see the code as it evolves.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A GitHub page itself wouldn't be put directly in an `iframe` ([because of the `X-Frame-Options: deny` HTTP header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7650758/6309)).

That leaves you with the [GitHub API for contents](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents): "Use the REST API to create, modify, and delete Base64 encoded content in a repository"

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path
```

Like: https://api.github.com/repos/ileathan/hubot-mubot/contents/src/mubot.coffee.

You should be able to [put that content in an `iframe` (as in this answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13958097/6309)

Comment: ITs 4:30 am i need to go to sleep so i cant check now, but is the returned content encrypted with my api key or is it just base64 encoded?? By the way thank you SO MUCH.

Comment: In the above link they state "Use the REST API to create, modify, and delete Base64 encoded content in a repository."

Comment: @andreagalle Good point. I have edited the answer to include that title.

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to hack the iframe and css a bit to get it to work without  tags in your document, but it's possible:

https://www.arctype.co/blog/embedding-github-gists-via-iframe

```
 <iframe frameborder=0 style="min-width: 200px; width: 60%; height: 460px;" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless" srcdoc='<html><body><style type="text/css">.gist .gist-data { height: 400px; }</style><script src="https://gist.github.com/sundbry/55bb902b66a39c0ff83629d9a8015ca4.js"></script></body></html>'></iframe>
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a concrete example of how this can be done via the GitHub API. We request the encoded content and insert it directly into the iframe.

```
<iframe id="github-iframe" src=""></iframe>
<script>
    fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/ileathan/hubot-mubot/contents/src/mubot.coffee')
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        }).then(function(data) {
            var iframe = document.getElementById('github-iframe');
            iframe.src = 'data:text/html;base64,' + encodeURIComponent(data['content']);
        });
</script>
```

Here's the code in action https://jsfiddle.net/j8brpdsg/2/

Comment: Pretty nice, but if you are trying to embed some github code into your page, the API returns a mangled result like this: https://imgur.com/a/ycmZmlq.

Answer (score 5):

I just found a way to do this using [Gist-it](http://gist-it.appspot.com/)

> Usage
>
> Take a github file url and prefix it with http://gist-it.appspot.com and embed the result within a  tag:
>
> ```
> <script src="http://gist-it.appspot.com/http://github.com/$file"></script>
> ```

Here's a test I just made. Works! :)

[image]