# Embed github rendered .md page as iframe

Tags: github, iframe, markdown

I would like to embed a .md page from github ([example](https://github.com/iml-wg/HEP-ML-Resources/blob/master/README.md)) in an HTML page (Actually only the rendered file content `<div id="readme" class="readme blob instapaper_body">`, not the headers and stuff around).

I looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43528476/4588453) but this does not embed the rendered markdown, but only the syntax highlighted source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GitHub provides an [API endpoint for rendering Markdown](https://developer.github.com/v3/markdown/#render-an-arbitrary-markdown-document). You can POST your raw Markdown content to `https://api.github.com/markdown` and use the response in your own application.

I recommend not hitting that API endpoint on every page load. You can request rendering on the back-end, cache the rendered content locally, and serve it from there. If the source Markdown changes you can re-render using GitHub's API.

Alternatively, you could put your Markdown into a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/) and use its built-in [embed functionality](https://help.github.com/articles/about-gists/#embedding-gists).

Comment: Nice but not what I'm looking for. for gist: I want to display the current status of the .md file in the repository (such that effectively everybody with write access to the github repository can edit the content of the webpage w/o buildbots). for the API: That would similarly require running something on my server to fetch and render the latest status, while I was looking for an embeding like provided by google documents, that lets the client browser fetch the data.

Comment: I don't think GitHub offers anything like that.

Comment: Too bad. I'll accept your answer anyways as overview of what can be done.