# Fetch text file to iframe src in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54101942/638445) I am trying to load a text file from a GitHub repository into an iframe:

```
<iframe id="github-iframe" src=""></iframe>
<script>
    fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/ileathan/hubot-mubot/contents/src/mubot.coffee')
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        }).then(function(data) {
            var iframe = document.getElementById('github-iframe');
            iframe.src = 'data:text/html;base64,' + encodeURIComponent(data['content']);
        });
</script>
```

This works on Chrome/Edge but on Firefox it treats the `iframe.src =` part like a download: it either prompts for what to do with it or downloads it to a randomly named temp file. Is there a way to fix that or a different method that will work for both Firefox and Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/ileathan/hubot-mubot/contents/src/mubot.coffee')
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      }).then(function(data) {
        var iframe = document.getElementById('github-iframe');
        iframe.contentDocument.body.innerText = atob(data['content']);
      });
```

You can read more about [encoding/decoding base64 here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64)

Comment: That did it and I could also add CSS styling for the text document which didn't work for src. Thanks!