iFrame will not populate webpage
I cannot get the following URL to appear in an iFrame: https://shapersource.github.io/SpaceTitan/
There does not appear to be a framekiller script and there is no x-frame in the header. Does anyone have any ideas? Would appreciate any help getting this to work as I need to display this 3D coordinate system via iframe.
This is the iframe I have tried:
<iframe src="https://shapersource.github.io/SpaceTitan/" width="295" height="328" frameborder="0"></iframe


Refer to this answer, it may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/28338933/25428314

Have you checked the browser's debugger?  If I put an iframe of that URL in a random HTML document, it complains:
Uncaught DOMException: Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object
Another cursory search for this issue reveals:
Error: Permission denied to access property "document"
I would bet that you are trying to embed an HTML file from another domain.  This is a common part of Cross-site scripting attacks, which many browsers no longer allow by default without some tinkering.
You can address this in a couple ways:

Make sure the HTML document with the iframe is hosted on the same domain on as your target URL (shaperesource.github.io)
Make sure that the shapersource.github.io page sets the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to the domain from which you are making the iframe
Make a copy of the JavaScript and HTML files locally so you can host it on the same domain.  (but double check licensing requirements; it appears to be GPL3 for the page you listed).

I was able to get that page properly embedded in an iframe by making a local copy of the JS and HTML files.

Thanks for the detailed response, Kevin. Would you mind sharing the local JS / HTML files you were able to get working?
Would I simply need to then host those files on the domain I am attempting to publish the iframe to?

I just did wget on the URL you provided (https://shapersource.github.io/SpaceTitan/).  Then, I ran wget on the javascript file that was referenced within that file (https://vectorgraphics.github.io/asymptote/base/webgl/asygl-1.02.js).
Yes, if you host them on the same domain, it should work because it avoids the cross-domain origin policy issue.
